# Can't find windows.winmd – if path specified, erros multiply

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017

I must work on a Visual Studio C++ solution done many years ago by a corporation that doen't have C++ experts.
I have few experience with C++, a lot with Visual Studio, but zero experience on those two together (when I used to program in C++ it was always for Linux). 
This solution has 9 projects and used to compile for Windows Embedded using Visual Studio 6.0 under Windows XP or Windows Vista.
I now must make it compile for x86 and ARM, using Visual Studio 2017 under Windows 7.

The only error I have on compiling is well-known:

`Can't find assembly windows.winmd. Specify the path using`/AI`or set the environment variable LIBPATH.`

If I follow the advice and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0` to the `/AI` parameter of the main project, I get 100+ compiler errors.

The previous error I had was: missing "platform.winmd", but after adding to /AI the path to that file the error disappeared. Solving the problem "windows.winmd" isn't trivial at all, because I have many of those files on my computer.
I just want to compile the project and I'm banging my head against this single error. Can someone help?

Comment: Something went very, very wrong if windows.winmd is necessary to compile such an ancient project.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess how that could have happened, but probably only posted the last error after wildly trying stuff instead of the first one.  Get old VS versions that can still tackle WindowsCE from an MSDN subscription.  You can't get VS6 anymore, aim for VS2008.  Or use an auction site, like Ebay.

Comment: What platforms are you targeting anyway?

Comment: @HansPassant I think he's targeting Windows 7 embedded or Windows 10 IOT Enterprise not Windows CE

Answer (score 0):

I would say with 99,999% probability, it is impossible to work with WinCE projects in VS2017. You really need to have old good VS 6.0 that is equipped with necessary toolchains and project types (indeed they're obsolete now).

Also, there is a non-zero chance you have to have lower OS version (something like WinXP or so) as some CE-time SDKs can be not compatible with Win10.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. This isn't a "Windows CE project", but just a "Windows project" that has always been compiled for Windows Embedded until yesterday.  Now I have to compile for x86.

Comment: In this case, there is no difference CE or Embedded. It is obsolete and removed from modern VS versions.

Comment: So how can I compile for x86 / Windows 7?

Comment: @Ernesto_Che, as I told before, just migrate to the 6th version of Visual Studio.

Comment: They already were using VS6. I suppose they wouldn't have asked my help if it were sufficient to set an "x86" switch in VS6.